# Big O or Big theta?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, asymptotic-complexity, big-o

Suppose we have a function f(n)= log n and another function g(n)=log n^2. The question is does f(n)=O(g(n)) or f(n)=big_Theta(g(n)). Since log n^2 = 2 log n then another way to put my question is can we use a fraction as constant k? For the big_Theta option, I would have something like k1=1/4 for the lower bound and k2=1 for the upper bound. Is this okay?

Obviously, k cannot be zero or negative but I am not sure about fraction and I did not see a clear answer on the web or in the books I looked in.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Both f(n)= Θ(g(n)) and f(n)= Θ(g(n)). Also please note that at the same time it is true that f(n)=O(g(n)). Intuitively big-oh means that f is bounded above by g(n)(i.e. it grows no faster than g). Big theta on the other hand means that f is bounded both above and below by g(i.e. it grows precisely as fast as g). Please note the last two sentences are not absolutely precise for the purpose of being easier to understand and focus on the intuitive meaning of this rather than its theory.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just wanted to be sure of this technical detail (k=fraction) and you seem to confirm my intuition.

Comment: @J.Mandy yes any real number can be used as k.